# How to find the Fourier trigonometric series of $f(t)$?

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

I'm new to Fourier series, and in a section of Laplace transform I found this problem:

> Determine the Fourier's trigonometric series of odd extension of the function $$f(t)=\left\lbrace -1\ \ if\ \ -\pi<t<0 \atop 1\ \ if \ \ 0<t<\pi \right.$$

Could anyone provide me some hints on what to calculate? and its relation to Laplace if any?

**Solution** After following the sugestion I found the numeric coefficients $a_0=0$ $a_k=0$, $b_k=\frac{2-2\cos(k\pi)}{k\pi}=\frac{2(1-(-1)^k)}{k\pi}$ and then $$f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi k}(1-(-1)^k)\sin(kt)$$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series. Assuming $f(t)$ is periodic with $T=2 \pi$, I believe the Laplace transform is $\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}{s}$.

Comment: @StevenClark thanks, with the formulas in wikipedia I was able to find $a_0, a_k, b_k$ and then $f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi k}(1-(-1)^k)\sin(kt)$

Comment: Your derivation is correct, but I posted an answer below that also defines and illustrates the Laplace transform of $f(t)$ which was part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes $f(t)$ is periodic as defined in formula (1) below.

---

$$f(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0\leq t<\pi  \\
 -1 & \pi \leq t<2 \pi  \\
 f(t \bmod (2 \pi )) & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}$$

---

Since $f(t)$ is an odd function of $t$ it can be represented by a Fourier sine serie as illustrated in formula (2) below.

---

$$f(t)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^n-1}{n}\,\sin(n\,t)\right)\tag{2}$$

---

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (2) for $f(t)$ evaluated at $N=100$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function defined in formula (1). The red discrete evaluation points illustrate the evaluation of formula (2) at multiples of $\pi$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (2) for f(t)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $f(t)$ in orange overlaid on blue reference function defined in formula (1)

---

The Laplace transform of $f(t)$ is illustrated in formula (3) below, and Mathematica indicates formula (3) below simplifies to formula (4) below.

---

$$\mathcal{L}_t[f(t)](y)=\int\limits_0^\infty f(t)\,e^{-t\,y}\,dt=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^n-1}{n^2+y^2}\right)\tag{3}$$

$$\mathcal{L}_t[f(t)](y)=\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{\pi\,y}{2}\right)}{y}\tag{4}$$

---

Figure (2) below illustrates formula (3) for $\mathcal{L}_t[f(t)](y)$ evaluated at $N=100$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function defined in formula (4).

---

[image: Illustration of formula (3) for Laplace transform of f(t)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of formula (3) for $\mathcal{L}_t[f(t)](y)$ in orange overlaid on blue reference function defined in formula (4)